# winsock error 10049 trying to bind

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a problem with server connection. When I try to bind the server to my external device IP I got a winsock error: 10049 Cannot assign requested address. Using localhost server works correctly.
This IP address: 192.168.0.202 ping successfully. 
I worked on win8.1. I turned off firewall and windows defender and it did not help.

Code with server implementation has been taken from http://www.planetchili.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3433

```
#include "Server.h"

Server::Server(int PORT, bool BroadcastPublically) //Port = port to broadcast on. BroadcastPublically = false if server is not open to the public (people outside of your router), true = server is open to everyone (assumes that the port is properly forwarded on router settings)
{
    //Winsock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) //If WSAStartup returns anything other than 0, then that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup.
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WinSock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }


    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.202"); 
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234); //Port
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket

    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); //Create socket to listen for new connections
    if (bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Bind the address to the socket, if we fail to bind the address..
    {
        std::string ErrorMsg = "Failed to bind the address to our listening socket. Winsock Error:" + std::to_string(WSAGetLastError());
        MessageBoxA(NULL, ErrorMsg.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Places sListen socket in a state in which it is listening for an incoming connection. Note:SOMAXCONN = Socket Oustanding Max Connections, if we fail to listen on listening socket...
    {
        std::string ErrorMsg = "Failed to listen on listening socket. Winsock Error:" + std::to_string(WSAGetLastError());
        MessageBoxA(NULL, ErrorMsg.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }
    serverptr = this;
}

bool Server::ListenForNewConnection()
{
    SOCKET newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen); //Accept a new connection
    if (newConnection == 0) //If accepting the client connection failed
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else //If client connection properly accepted
    {
        std::cout << "Client Connected! ID:" << TotalConnections << std::endl;
        Connections[TotalConnections] = newConnection; //Set socket in array to be the newest connection before creating the thread to handle this client's socket.
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ClientHandlerThread, (LPVOID)(TotalConnections), NULL, NULL); //Create Thread to handle this client. The index in the socket array for this thread is the value (i).
        //std::string MOTD = "MOTD: Welcome! This is the message of the day!.";
        //SendString(TotalConnections, MOTD);
        TotalConnections += 1; //Incremenent total # of clients that have connected
        return true;
    }
}

bool Server::ProcessPacket(int ID, Packet _packettype)
{
    switch (_packettype)
    {
    case P_ChatMessage: //Packet Type: chat message
    {
        std::string Message; //string to store our message we received
        if (!GetString(ID, Message)) //Get the chat message and store it in variable: Message
            return false; //If we do not properly get the chat message, return false
                          //Next we need to send the message out to each user
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalConnections; i++)
        {
            if (i == ID) //If connection is the user who sent the message...
                continue;//Skip to the next user since there is no purpose in sending the message back to the user who sent it.
            if (!SendString(i, Message)) //Send message to connection at index i, if message fails to be sent...
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to send message from client ID: " << ID << " to client ID: " << i << std::endl;
            }
        }
        //std::cout << "Processed chat message packet from user ID: " << ID << std::endl;

        if(Message == "go")
            std::cout << "MESSAGE:GO!"  << std::endl;
        else if(Message == "left")
            std::cout << "MESSAGE: GO LEFT!"  << std::endl;
        else if (Message == "right")
            std::cout << "MESSAGE:GO RIGHT!" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "MESSAGE:DO NOTHING!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    default: //If packet type is not accounted for
    {
        std::cout << "Unrecognized packet: " << _packettype << std::endl; //Display that packet was not found
        break;
    }
    }
    return true;
}

void Server::ClientHandlerThread(int ID) //ID = the index in the SOCKET Connections array
{
    Packet PacketType;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!serverptr->GetPacketType(ID, PacketType)) //Get packet type
            break; //If there is an issue getting the packet type, exit this loop
        if (!serverptr->ProcessPacket(ID, PacketType)) //Process packet (packet type)
            break; //If there is an issue processing the packet, exit this loop
    }
    std::cout << "Lost connection to client ID: " << ID << std::endl;
    closesocket(serverptr->Connections[ID]);
    return;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no connect step here. This is a server. It binds and accepts. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The conditional statement where you bind to `INADDR_ANY` vs `192.168.0.202` does not do what you think it does.  In general you should always bind to `INADDR_ANY`. If you are trying to restrict connectivity to an IP address range, you either need to handle that after you accept call or use a firewall rule to block unwanted connections.

Comment: @EPJ It did not bind. I got an error "Failed to bind the address to our listening socket. Winsock Error:10049"

Comment: So please correct your post, including your title.

Comment: Is `192.168.0.202` the address of your server machine or the external device?

Comment: It is an address of the external device.

Comment: @Paulina you cannot bind a socket to an external address, only to an address on the local machine. If you have an external IP, that implies you have a NAT router, which means you need to enable port forwarding to pass outside traffic from the NAT to your server.

Answer (score 4):

The `bind()` function is used to specify which address of the server system is used to accept connections from remote clients, not to specify which remote client is allowed to connect to the server. The `bind()` function can only be used with addresses that are valid for the server itself, not for addresses of remote devices or hosts.

In order to limit which remote host is allowed to connect to your server, you need to accept the connection and validate the remote address at that time. If the address is not the correct one, the connection is closed.

In general, you want to use `INADDR_ANY` unless your server is multi-homed (more than one physical connection to more than one network), and only then if you are trying to restrict connections to one of the networks to which your server is attached.

Comment: @Paulina you are receiving the same error on the `listen()` call?

Comment: No, sorry my falult. Still bind() function error ;( 
I have edited the code. What if I want to connect only to this external maschine IP?

Comment: @Paulina accept the connection and validate the remote address. If it does not match, close the socket and wait for the next connection.

Answer (score 1):

Winsock returns the error flag 10049 (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL) through its API `WSAGetLastError` whenever an application tries to bind to an invalid ip Addrress.

binding to a specific IP address means that whenever you run the program (server) the address should be valid (available) but however DHCP gives you dynamic ip addresses everytime you disconnect/connect your adapter so you the address you bound the server the previous time is not valid to correct it open cmd and enter :

```
ipconfig
```

you'll get the list of ip4/ip6 addresses then you can pick one of them and bind your server to however this method is really dull so the alternative is to bind to `INADDR_ANY` so you  let the system do the job for you.

you need only from the client to enter the server address and port and connect.